# Regarding Login to a different domain in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a domain let say xyz.com and in my page, I have an Iframe with the page from other domain let say, www.abc.com/home.aspx. However, abc.com has authentication implemented, because of which it redirects to login.aspx. Is there a way so that i can call the login page of abc.com internally and get there cookies created from their side and then access their home page. I am using asp.net.

Thanks

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/why-is-the-same-origin-policy-so-important

Answer (score 0):

When the iframe abc.com authentication succeeds, the iframe can open another child iframe page under xyz.com to set the authentication cookie for xyz.com. Then the user browser has both domain cookies.

Comment: I do not want user to see the login screen of abc.com, it will done in the background programmitically. Any suggestions??

Comment: But in your question, you say user autheticate at abc.com. Then users login first at abc.com, and then get redirected to xyz.com page with an iframe of abc.com inside?

Comment: Ok, I am rephrasing it, User has a login in xyz.com and also in abc.com, he just logs in Xyz.com (Main Page), we have to auto login him in abc.com  (without single sign on). So, i am looking to do the abc.com authentication in code behind and redirect him to the page he wants in abc.com. Also i want to grab the cookies for further request to other pages of abc.com.